# Persistent CORS issues with Python-based Google Cloud Functions, even using the Docs example

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cors

CORS is causing a highly persistent error for my web app when trying to query a Cloud Function with `axios`. I have numerous Node.js Cloud Functions that work seemlessly with my Flutter apps, but in this Next.js app I specifically need to leverage a Python Cloud Function.

I've tried handling CORS numerous ways, but even if I just literally use the [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-cors#functions_http_cors-python)' example I still get the CORS error. Here's the Cloud Function code:

```
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def myFun(request):
    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    if request.method == "OPTIONS":
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Max-Age": "3600",
        }

        return ("", 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}

    return ("Hello World!", 200, headers)
```

This is how I call the function:

```
            axios
              .post(
                "https://myurl.cloudfunctions.net/myFun",
                body,
                {
                  headers: {
                    Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  },
                },
              )
              .then((response) => {
                console.log("Raw response: ", response.data);
                const completion = response.data;
                botMessage.content = completion;
                console.log("Clean response: ", completion);
                get().onNewMessage(botMessage);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error(
                  "Error while calling Cloud Function:",
                  error,
                );
              });
```

The error:

> ```
> message: "Network Error", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_NETWORK", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }
> app-index.js:33:22
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
> ```

I tried changing the "GET" in the docs example to "POST".

Comment: Check if your function is returning something other than HTTP Status 2xx. Apps often do not return CORS headers on errors. The browser reports a CORS error instead of showing you the actual HTTP error.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks. I'm not seeing a proper status code in the browser console. Its got the common CORS Blocked message and some very long, mostly-generic-looking axios error...
`Error while calling Cloud Function: 
Object { stack: "AxiosError@webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:24:19\nhandleError@webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:172:14\n", message: "Network Error", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_NETWORK", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }` This was both before and after I changed GET to POST.

Comment: On the GCP side it doesn't show anything.

Comment: The browser will block showing you an error due to CORS. You can either use a tool like Wireshark or report the HTTP status in your backend code. add logging for each HTTP request and response. The key is logging the response from you app.

Comment: @JohnHanley OK thanks, I will try. I mean it's got those `console.log()` statements and `console.error` but is there somewhere different I should put them?

Comment: I do not know the framework you are using. Usually, you can write your own error handlers so that you can control responses and custom error messages.

Comment: I think you are confusing frontend and backend. The backend generates the response. That is where you must include CORS headers for error responses. In the code you posted, you are not handling error responses. For your frontend, the browser will block your code seeing error responses if the required CORS headers are not present.

Comment: @JohnHanley Oh, you mean in the Cloud Function then? Yes, I can try to do that.

Comment: @Hack-R Because your client includes a header named `Authorization` in the request, a necessary condition for CORS preflight to succeed is for you to list `Authorization` as an allowed request header in your CORS config. However, implementing CORS "manually" is error-prone; for instance, contrary to what your code implies, [not all `OPTIONS` requests are preflight requests](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#4-categorise-requests-correctly). I encourage you to rely on a proven CORS middleware library instead.

Comment: @jub0bs There were so many iterations before I finally got to the version that worked for me below, but yes, that was probably part of it. I do have `Authorization` below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I went through so many iterations of this to get it working it's hard to keep track, but the key final change was changing this (which was not in the example I started with above, but a later iteration, below):

```
return None
```

to this:

```
return '', 400, headers
```

and this

```
return response_json, 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

to this:

```
return response_json, 200, headers
```

in this iteration (which is built off of a version of the Hello World above in my question that I got to work, but then - after modifying with my real Cloud Function logic - needed the aforementioned changes):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import functions_framework
import json

@functions_framework.http
def myFun(request):
# Set CORS headers for the preflight request
if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
    # Allows POST and GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
    # header and caches preflight response for 3600 seconds (1 hour)
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
    }

    return ('', 204, headers)

# Set CORS headers for the main request
headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}

# Read the CSV file with prompt embeddings and completions
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')

# project-specific logic went here

# Check something specific to my project here
if this_data is None:
    return '', 400, headers

# Calculate stuff
stuff = this_data

response_data = {'my_stuff': stuff}
response_json = json.dumps(response_data)
return response_json, 200, headers
```